# splitting a string and concatenating it back together

Tags: r, concatenation, strsplit

I've been trying to split a string in R and then joining it back together but none of the tricks have worked for what I need.

Here's the code:

I take pre-saved sentences in R

```
sentences[1]
```

and split it

```
s <- str_split(sentences[1])
```

this is what I get:

```
[1] "The"     "birch"   "canoe"   "slid"    "on"      "the"     "smooth"  "planks."
```

Now when I try to join this back together I get backslashes

```
toString(s) 

"c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

paste produces the same result:

```
> paste(s)
[1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

I tried using str_split_fixed and wrap it into a vector, but it joins the sentence back together with a comma, even if I ask it not to.

```
v <- as.vector(str_split_fixed(sentences[1], " ", 5))
toString(v, sep="")

[1] "The, birch, canoe, slid, on the smooth planks."
```

I thought maybe str_split_i or str_split_1 could solve it as according to the documentation in theory it should, but that's what I get when I try to use it

```
"could not find function "str_split_1" "
```

Are there any other ways to join back a string after splitting it without it producing commas or backslashes?..

**Important**
saving a split result into a variable and then pasting, collapsing etc is not the same as just paste a vector like this

```
paste(c("bla", "bla"), collapse = " ")

> paste(c("The","birch", "canoe"), collapse = ' ')
[1] "The birch canoe"
> paste(s, collapse=" ")
[1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

Comment: Try the `collapse` argument in `paste`, i.e. `paste(c("The","birch", "canoe"), collapse = ' ')`

Comment: It doesn't work. When you just paste a vector, it works. But saving the split result in a var and pasting it - doesn't.

Comment: What you are saying does not stand. What is `s`? What is `sentence[1]`? Why don't you have the pattern of splitting in `str.split()`? Please add more information

Comment: as I said sentences is a pre-difined list of sentences in R. Try running it and you will see there are many sentences. You can tap into any of them, for my example I chose sentences[1]

Comment: Ok I see your mistake and I reopened the question

Comment: Presumably after splitting you want to do some operation on it before putting it back together.  What is the operation?  Depending on what it is there may be a better way than splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your error comes from `str_split` returning a list, i.e.

```
s <- str_split(sentences[1], pattern = ' ')
s
[[1]]
[1] "The"     "birch"   "canoe"   "slid"    "on"      "the"     "smooth"  "planks."
```

So If you try

```
paste(s, collapse = ' ')
# [1] "c(\"The\", \"birch\", \"canoe\", \"slid\", \"on\", \"the\", \"smooth\", \"planks.\")"
```

The correct way is to unlist first,

```
paste(unlist(s), collapse = ' ')
#[1] "The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks."
```

However if you have many sentences you need to loop, i.e.

```
s <- str_split(sentences[1:3], pattern = ' ')
sapply(s, paste, collapse = ' ')
#[1] "The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks."  "Glue the sheet to the dark blue background." "It's easy to tell the depth of a well."
```